# JSON stringified string breaks inside the data attribute when has a space separated value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

```
 var dataObj=  {
      "Cast_Code": "NA",
      "Mat_Code": "xxxx",
      "Pin_Num": "xxxx",
      "MatDetail": [
        {
          "Batch_Number": "Patch PA",
          "Batch_Expiry": "No Expiry",
          "Batch_Quantity": "xxx",
          "Return_Qty": "0.00"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am trying to assign the above object as an attribute to an element like this:

```
content +='<div class="save_data" data-savereturn='+JSON.stringify(dataObj)+'></div>';
```

But on viewing the source it appears in the HTML like:

```
<div class="save_return" data-savereturn="{"Cast_Code": "NA",...,
      "MatDetail": [
        {                //Notice the double quote between "Patch PA"
          "Batch_Number": "Patch" pa","batch_expiry": "no expiry","batch_quantity": "xxx","return_qty": "0.00""
        }
      ]
    }"></div>
```

I further tried

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataObj));
```

which logs the output correct without being broken by the double quote as in the case of assigning it to the `data-savereturn`.

This **dataObj** gets created in a **jQuery.each** loop which is then assigned to corresponding HTML elements.

Unable to figure out the breaking of JSON which is truncating & lowercasing of the portion after the space.

It doesn't happens when the word has no space in between i.e

```
"Batch_Number": "PatchPA",
```

**Update:**

on
start quotes double (")

```
content +='<div class="save_data" data-savereturn="'+JSON.stringify(dataObj)+'"></div>';

    
    it shows:

    <div class="save_return" data-savereturn="{" Cast_Code":"na","Mat_Code":"xyz","Pin_Num":"xyz","batchdetail":[{"batch_number":"patch="" na","batch_expiry":"no="" expiry","batch_quantity":"20","return_qty":"0.00"}]}"=""></div>

    jQuery('.selector').data('savereturn')
     gives
    {
      "savereturn": "{"
    }
    which gives an error on JSON.parse "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"
```

changed the start quotes to single (')

```
     content +="<div class='save_data' data-savereturn='"+JSON.stringify(dataObj)+"'></div>";
    
        <div class="save_return" data-savereturn="{"Request_Code":"NA";"Mat_Code":"xx";"In_num":"xx","BatchDetail":[{"Batch_Number":"Batch NA","Batch_Expiry":"No Expiry","Batch_Quantity":"10","Return_Qty":"0.00"}]}"></div>

jQuery('sel').data('savereturn') gives:
{
  "Cast_Code": "NA",
  "Mat_Code": "tttt",
  "Tin_Number": "ppp",
  "PatchDetail": [
    {
      "Batch_Number": "Patch NA",
      "Batch_Expiry": "No Expiry",
      "Batch_Quantity": "10",
      "Return_Qty": "0.00"
    }
  ]
}
which also give error on JSON.parse
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

2nd one looks correct but still having JSON invalid.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes

Comment: `content +='<div class="save_data" data-savereturn="'+JSON.stringify(dataObj)+'"></div>';`

Comment: @Callam that would be even worse.  Swap the quotes.

Comment: `<div class="save_data" data-savereturn="${JSON.stringify(dataObj).replace(/"/g, '\\"')}"></div>`

Comment: Often it worked without any quotes `data-savereturn='+JSON.stringify(dataObj)+'>`

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: For me this worked better JSON.stringify(dataObj).replace(/"/g, '&quot;')

Comment: @DanielBailey please make that an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put quotes around an attribute that contains spaces, as well as some other punctuation characters, so it's best to *always* quote your attributes. Since the JSON will contain double quotes, you should use single quotes around the attribute.

```
content +="<div class='save_data' data-savereturn='"+JSON.stringify(dataObj)+"'></div>";
```

Note that this won't work properly if there are any single quotes in `dataObj`; they won't be encoded to prevent from terminating the `data-savereturn` attribute.

If you're using jQuery, it would be easier IMO to create the element like this:

```
var element = $("<div>", {
    "class": "save_data",
    data: { "savereturn": dataObj }
});
```

and this also solves that problem. In plain JavaScript this would be:

```
let element = document.createElement("div");
element.classList.add("save_data");
element.datalist.savereturn = JSON.stringify(dataObj);
```

Comment: would this approach concatenate on an already running string variable like `content +=`?

Comment: If you use this approach you would generally use `.append()` to add the element to a DIV, rather than dealing with HTML strings.

Comment: Actually `content` contains whole html of page appended into it over  several loops and conditions and this is needed to be attached along.This is then assigned to a central div by using `.html()` method of jQuery.Dont know if it is the right approach but it is an ongoing thing so little chance to change that.

Comment: Then use the first part of the answer.

Comment: There are pros and cons. Constructing the HTML string and inserting it into the DOM at the end is fast. But you can run into problems if you're not careful about the syntax. When you're inserting complex data like JSON, the latter could be an issue.

Comment: Updated some findings in the question.

Comment: I still don't understand why it sometimes work without even enclosing inside a quote(double or single) Which I believe is some sort of intelligent browser parsing.`data-savereturn='"+JSON.stringify(dataObj)+"'` yields the object in data attribute without breakage problem at space.

Comment: You have single quotes around the JSON. Use `console.log(content)` and you'll see them.

Comment: This will fail if the JSON data contains single quotes. Do proper HTML escaping or use the DOM

Comment: @Bergi Which is why the jQuery programmatic approach is better.

Comment: Yes, but the answer should explain that, not say "*you should use single quotes around the attribute*"

Comment: I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score -2):

This topic is too old, but I think others like me would come across the same issue while stringify some object that contains a value whith spaces.

A possible approach to deal this problem is to replace the value with space by ' ', a "non-breaking space" special char code like this:

var Batch_Number = value_from_somewhere.replace(" ", ' ');

Comment: That's a really bad idea. It messes with the data in absolutely unexpected ways.

Comment: no such thing as non breaking space... just **empty space**.